# What is level 1, 2, 3 support in web hosting or network support?

Tags: untagged

Often when I send a support ticket to some web host, if they cannot handle it they will say something like "We will escalate this to level 3". What exactly is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no "official" definition of what levels 1, 2 and 3 are.

Generally speaking, though, as you progress up through the levels, people's expertise increases, as does their ability to identify the problem and provide resolution. The problem is that as people's skills and experience increase, so do their salary requirements. As such, as you progress up through the levels, the number of people staffing those levels will typically decrease. The hope is that the majority of problems will be able to be solved lower down in the support organization, leaving the few upper-level support techs to deal with the few technically-challenging issues that arise.

Answer (score 0):

It's just the next level in the support organization.  If the call center / help desk / person on the phone is Level 1, then the next level (Level 2) could be some junior technician, and so on until you reach the most experienced level.